# two independent events with the same probability $p \left( 0<p<1\right)$.Find the probability of occurrence of at least one of the two events

Tags: probability

Consider two independent events with the same probability $p \left( 0<p<1\right)$.Then the probability of occurrence of at least one of the two events is
(A) the same for all $p$.
(B) linearly increasing in $p$.
(C) strictly convex in $p$.
(D) strictly concave in $p$.
Try:
Let $A, B$ be the two independent events. Given that $P(A) =p$ and $P(B) =p$. Now the probability of occurrence of at least one of the two events is
$P(A\cap \bar{B})$,$P(\bar{A}\cap B)$, $P(A\cap B)$
Now $P(A\cap \bar{B})=p(1-p)$
$P(\bar{A}\cap B)=(1-p) p$
$P(A\cap B)=p^2$
Then the required function is
$f(p) =p(1-p)+(1-p)p+p^2=2p-p^2\implies f''(p)=-2< 0$ .
Hence option (D) is correct.
Am I correct now?
$\color{blue} {Edit}:$Edited after Teresa Lisbon' s comment.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of linearly increasing, strictly convex, strictly concave in the context of a one-variable function? The function "probability of occurrence of at least one of the two events" is a function of $p$, so everything relates to that function. Furthermore, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A \cap B)$ equals? (And if $A,B$ are independent then so are $A,B^c$, and $A^c,B$ and the rest, so that will simplify your expression considerably). If you have an attempt to make following my comments, then please edit your question, thanks once again.

Comment: For one variable linearly increasing means $f'(x) \ge 0$ and convex means $f''(x) \ge 0$ and concave means $f''(x) \le 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Small points : *strict* means all the signs lose equality, so $strictly$ convex is $f''(x)>0$ and similarly for strictly concave. Also, linearly increasing is a bit confusing for me, because I think *linearly* increasing means that the slope $f'(x)$ is a positive constant number. But yes, otherwise I  think you have a good grasp of what's going on. Now what you need is to find $f(p)$ itself. (+1) @Math-Learner

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Nice and beautiful hint. (+1)

Comment: Absolutely fine! For another way, note that "at least one occurs" is the opposite of "both don't occur" whose probability is $(1-p)^2$, so you can also get $f(p) = 1-(1-p)^2$, and again if you differentiate that twice you get $-2$, so the same result follows. I'm now going to ask you to answer your own question , since you got it on your own. I basically need an excuse to up vote you twice!

Comment: Yes, I have  been able to think that. It was a nice experience learning from you.